# Diffrence between block chain smart contract platforms ?!!

Tags: platform, blockchain, smartcontracts

kinda new to block chain technologies and going to work on a project of a smart contract based on block-chain .

i was wondering what are the platforms available ? 
what is the difference between them ? (points of comparison)

Help plz :) !!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the term “Contract” it has not communicated clearly. Assuming you have the fair understanding on “what is Blockchain”. Let me give a perspective – it is contact between parties stored on the Blockchain or any computation that takes place on a Blockchain. Referring to some of technical forums, the answer to contract platforms depends on the what type of “Contract”? Mainly any one of the two types of contract (generally refers to the capabilities you looking for).

1. Smart contract code: This is to identify a specific technology – code that is stored, verified, and executed on a Blockchain. Example, Ethereum or Eris platform, whose primary purpose is to be a platform for smart contract code. The platform provides code that could articulate a conditional financial transaction, While the code could articulate a conditional financial transaction (“send 1 Ether from Alice to Bob on Jan 1, 2017”), it could also be a governance application that controls account permissions (“if Alice has voted yes, remove Bob’s voting rights over Application X and notify the following accounts…”).

You can make smart contract code using Ethereum or Eris Blockchain-based application. Please refer to their respective website. You will find lots of materials. There are may others as well.

And the other type of smart contract,

2. Smart legal contracts (the real world): This is to a specific application of that technology – as a complement, or substitute, for legal contracts. This type of contract does not limit only to be executed using Blockchain platform.  It is still a debatable… as many commercial, clauses may not be always suitably represented using code. But in future the integration of 1 & 2 would most likely replace some of traditional legal contract languages.

Comment: it's a legal contract between the insurer and insurance.

Comment: yes, contract can be written using ethereum platform.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Blockchain itself can be used for developing Smart Contracts, though it is a little bit challenging for beginners.

[Bitcoin Contracts](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contract#Example_1:_Providing_a_deposit)

Ethereum is one of the most widely used Blockchain Platform for writing smart contracts.

[Solidity Smart Contracts](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.1/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html)

You can also use Hyperledger for writing smart contracts / chain codes.

[Smart Contracts on IBM Blockchain](https://developer.ibm.com/code/patterns/create-and-execute-blockchain-smart-contracts/)

NEO is emerging as another popular Blockchain platform for authoring smart contracts.

[Developing Smart Contracts in NEO](http://docs.neo.org/en-us/sc/introduction.html)